# delete row table with button sweetalert2 php mysql ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sweetalert2

I want to delete a book in one of row of my table with ajax and I can't do it.
I have a MVC structure of my php code
My routeur index.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    define("URL", str_replace("index.php","",(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http").
     "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]"));

      require_once "controllers/BooksController.controller.php";
    $bookController = new BooksController;

         try{
           if(empty($_GET['page'])){
          require "views/welcome.view.php";
          } else {
            $url = explode("/", filter_var($_GET['page']),FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

        switch($url[0]){
            case "welcome" : require "views/welcome.view.php";
            break;
            case "book" : 
                if(empty($url[1])){
                    $bookController->displayBooks();
                } else if($url[1] === "s") {
                    $bookController->deleteBook($url[2]);
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("not exist");
                }
            break;
            default : throw new Exception("not exist");
          }
       }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
      $msg = $e->getMessage();
       require "views/error.view.php";
     }

In my views/books.view.php

    <?php 
     ob_start(); 
      if(!empty($_SESSION['alert'])) :
      ?>
      <div class="alert alert-<?= $_SESSION['alert']['type'] ?>" role="alert">
        <?= $_SESSION['alert']['msg'] ?>
    </div>
   <?php 
     unset($_SESSION['alert']);
    endif; 
     ?>
      <table class="table text-center">
         <tr class="table-dark">
           <th>Title</th>
           <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
         <?php 
             for($i=0; $i < count($books);$i++) : 
          ?>
         <tr>
           <td class="align-middle"><a href="<?= URL ?>books/l/<?= $books[$i]->getId(); ?>"><?= 
         $books[$i]->getTitle(); ?></a></td>
           <td class="align-middle">
              <button class="btn btn-danger" id="sweet" data-url="<?= URL ?>books/s/<?= $books[$i]- 
                 >getId(); ?>" data-id="<?= $books[$i]->getId(); ?>">Delete</button>
            </td>
            </tr>
           <?php endfor; ?>
     </table>
     <button type="button"  class="btn btn-secondary disabled">Sweet</button>

     <?php
       $content = ob_get_clean();
        $title = "Books";
        require "template.php";
      ?>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '#sweet', function(e){
        var bookUrl= $(this).data('url'); // http://localhost/shop/books/s/5
        SwalDelete(bookUrl);
        e.preventDefault();
        });
      });
 
      function SwalDelete(bookUrl){
  
        Swal.fire({
           title: 'Delete this book ?',
           text: "the book was deleted in database !",
           icon: 'warning',
           showCancelButton: true,
           confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
           cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
           cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
           confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
           },function(isConfirm){
             if(isConfirm){
             $.ajax({
            url: bookUrl,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(resp){
              console.log('here cool !!! ');
                        window.location.href =bookUrl;
                    }
           })
          }
         return false;
      }
       );
 
      }
 
       </script>
```

When i click on the 'Yes, delete it!' button, popup is closed but i have any action to delete the row and any error on my console developer in chrome navigator.
the bookUrl passed to ajax is  http://localhost/shop/books/s/5 but is not redirect to the controller and i have no error message.
Any idea to help me ?